# documentum rest services issue

Tags: documentum, opentext

**Documentum authentication error**
I am able to run [repository list api](https://localhost:8080/dctm-rest/repositories) but when I am running **[repository detail api](http://localhost:8080/dctm-rest/repositories/%7Brepository-name%7D)** and in authorization i am passing username :- dmadmin and password : - password .
I am getting

```
{
"status": 401,
"code": "E_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR",
"message": "An internal server error occurs.",
"details": "Authentication failed.",
"id": "d9e6f6f5-0e30-4b0d-9748-56e0eae63874"
}
```

which authentication credentials i need to pass to run these API.

I have tried all the possible credentials of postgresSQL,server.

Comment: Please ask this question to the person that maintains the documentum instance. We cannot help you if the question is related to the setup of the documentum instance you are trying to access and not documentum in general.

Comment: You should use Documentum repository (docbase) user credentials and not PostgreSQL server user credentials. For dmadmin user the password will be the same as is into the OS where the Documentum Content server is installed. As @GoGoris said ask your Documentum administrator.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using postman o some REST client you need to send the credentials as a basic auth header. If you're accesing through the browser, you just need to pass the credentials (always from a dctm user)